# failed to deploy application to cloud foundry

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I am getting below error. Spent 3 hours but not success to resolve. Anyone has idea on this?

```
20-Dec-2021 15:26:16    2021-12-20T15:26.16-0500 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Java Buildpack v4.46 (offline) | https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack#9ada8526
20-Dec-2021 15:26:16    2021-12-20T15:26.16-0500 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Downloading Jvmkill Agent 1.16.0_RELEASE from https://java-buildpack.cloudfoundry.org/jvmkill/bionic/x86_64/jvmkill-1.16.0-RELEASE.so (found in cache)
20-Dec-2021 15:26:17    2021-12-20T15:26.16-0500 [STG/0]      ERR [Buildpack]                      ERROR Finalize failed with exception #<RuntimeError: Unable to find cached file for https://java-buildpack.cloudfoundry.org/openjdk/bionic/x86_64/bellsoft-jre15.0.2%2B10-linux-amd64.tar.gz>
20-Dec-2021 15:26:17    2021-12-20T15:26.16-0500 [STG/0]      ERR Unable to find cached file for https://java-buildpack.cloudfoundry.org/openjdk/bionic/x86_64/bellsoft-jre15.0.2%2B10-linux-amd64.tar.gz
20-Dec-2021 15:26:17    2021-12-20T15:26.16-0500 [STG/0]      ERR Failed to compile droplet: Failed to run finalize script: exit status 1
20-Dec-2021 15:26:17    2021-12-20T15:26.16-0500 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Downloading Open Jdk JRE 15.0.2_10 from https://java-buildpack.cloudfoundry.org/openjdk/bionic/x86_64/bellsoft-jre15.0.2%2B10-linux-amd64.tar.gz Exit status 223
20-Dec-2021 15:26:17    2021-12-20T15:26.17-0500 [STG/0]      OUT Cell 9719833a-199a-48b8-bc4a-e652774f8369 stopping instance b9bd8708-4155-4eca-bb89-3090297db6e2
20-Dec-2021 15:26:17    2021-12-20T15:26.17-0500 [STG/0]      OUT Cell 9719833a-199a-48b8-bc4a-e652774f8369 destroying container for instance b9bd8708-4155-4eca-bb89-3090297db6e2
20-Dec-2021 15:26:17    2021-12-20T15:26.17-0500 [API/2]      ERR Failed to stage build: staging failed
```

Comment: needs more stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

First, you are using an "offline" version of the Java buildpack. This means that the buildpack is limited to using dependencies that are bundled with the buildpack. You're using version 4.46, so you can see the list of what is bundled with it here.

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/releases/tag/v4.46

This includes Java 1.8.0_312, 11.0.13_8 and 17.0.1_12.

Second, you are requesting Java 15 to be installed. The buildpack is failing because it does not have access to Java 15, as explained above.

The default version of Java that the buildpack will use is Java 8. Since it's picking something else here, that must be due to user input. Check your env variables, i.e. `cf env`, and look for ones starting with `JBP_CONFIG_*`. There is likely one set that is configuring the buildpack to use Java 15.

See [docs](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/#configuration-and-extension) for more details on how the Java buildpack can be configured.

Comment: Yeah I degraded java version to 11 and its working as expected. Also, Cloud Foundry don't support java 15.